# Is it possible and/or safe to use Parse to allow users to transfer money to eachother?

Tags: security, parse-platform, financial

In my app, I want users to be able to add money to their account, and send it to other members when certain services are rendered.

Is there a safe and straightforward to do this with Parse.com? If not, is there a third party someone can recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Parse actually released something for mobile payment processing. It's called 'Stripe.' http://stripe.com/

Comment: But I'm looking for some way to let users add funds to their account and then securely store their balance and transfer to other users